# Monadic creation of vectors (or: can someone type annotate this for me?)

Tags: haskell, monads

I came across the following piece of code as part of [this Redddit sub-thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/cw6ct/why_haskell_isnt_popular_in_the_industry_9_reasons/c0vqw2m) discussing an implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
randomIs g n = fill g 0
  where
    v = enumFromN 0 n

    fill g i = when (i < n) $ do
            let (x,g') = randomR (i, n-1) g
            G.swap v i x
            fill g' (i+1)
```

(I guess `G` refers to `Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable`... right?).  Having never created vectors monadically before, I'm struggling to grasp this, especially with no type annotations. Doesn't `v` have type `Data.Vector Int`? How come one can pass it to `G.swap` then? Won't it have to be thawed first?

I might have just misunderstood `Data.Vector.Generic`, but if someone could clarify the above (by adding type annotations, perhaps?), I'd appreciate it.

**Addendum:** Here's my own attempt at adding type annotations:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UVect
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UMVect
import qualified System.Random as R
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST

randomPermutation :: forall a. (R.RandomGen a) => a -> Int -> UVect.Vector Int
randomPermutation g n = runST newVect
    where
      newVect :: ST s (UVect.Vector Int)
      newVect = UVect.unsafeThaw (UVect.enumFromN 0 n) >>= \v ->
                fill v 0 g >>
                UVect.unsafeFreeze v

      fill x i gen = when (i < n) $
                     let (j, gen') = R.randomR (i, n-1) gen in
                     UMVect.unsafeSwap x i j >>
                     fill x (i+1) gen'
```

As you can see, I'm avoiding `Data.Vector.Generic` to rule out the error source caused by perhaps not understanding it right. I'm also doing things in the `ST` monad.

In my head, the type of `fill` should be

```
UMVect.MVector (ST s (UVect.Vector Int)) Int -> Int -> a -> ST s ()
```

but GHC objects. Any hints? Again: It typechecks if I don't annotate `fill`.

**Sidenote:** I'd also like `randomPermutation` to return the updated random number generator. Thus, I'd need `fill` to also handle the generator's state. With my current type confusion, I don't see how to do that neatly. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The compile error is telling us:

```
Expected type: ST s (UMVect.MVector (ST s (UVect.Vector Int)) Int)
Actual type: ST s (UMVect.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (ST s)) Int)
```

So, changing the type signature of `fill` to `UMVect.MVector (PrimState (ST s)) Int -> Int -> a -> ST s ()` (adding `import Control.Monad.Primitive` too) solves the problem!

Comment: Aha, thank you. I'll not set this as the accepted answer yet though, in case someone can explain the types in the original code.